# How to find the most frequent value in an array without using Arrays class (e.g, no sorting) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This code is to find a statistical mode in every given dataset.

```
public double mode() {
    if(data==null) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else if(data.length==0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else {
        int[] counter1=new int[data.length];
        int counter2=0;
        double mode = Double.NaN;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[i] == data[j]) {
                    counter1[i]++;
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (counter1[i] > counter1[j]) {
                    counter2=i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter2 > 0) {
            mode = data[counter2];
        }else if (counter2 < 0){
            mode = Double.NaN;

        }
        return mode;
    }
```

With the following datasets:

1. [20.0, 20.0]
2. [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]

I am expecting to get the variable mode to have:

```
For dataset 1: mode=20.0 
For dataset 2: mode=NaN
```

But, here is what I am getting:

```
For dataset 1: mode=NaN
For dataset 2: mode=NaN
```

How should I achieve that result and have the method to save correct statistical mode to variable mode every time?

DISCLAIMER: I cannot use any Helper methods (ex. Array)

Comment: How about `[1, 1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: It gives me mode=NaN which is a correct value.

Comment: Instead of making 2 separate conditions for `data==null` and `data.length==0` when they both `return Double.NaN;` why not just put them together `data==null || data.length==0`. Also, I don't see `data` in the signature where is that coming from?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: The data is coming from a different class. They are passed through this method. 

The data I gave as examples are the data being passed to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public static Double getPopularElement(double[] a) {
  int count = 1, tempCount;
  double popular = a[0];
  double temp;
  boolean isUnique = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < (a.length - 1); i++) {
    temp = a[i];
    tempCount = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (temp == a[j])
        tempCount++;
    }
    if (tempCount > count) {
      isUnique = true;
      popular = temp;
      count = tempCount;
    } else if (tempCount == count) {
      isUnique = false;
    }
  }
  return isUnique ? popular : Double.NaN;
}
```

Test Runs:

```
{1.0, 2.0, 3.0} == NaN

{1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0} == NaN

{1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0} == 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you! But I cannot use any other methods than what is basic to Java. Like for, length, while...etc no Collections, Set, Iterator, hasNext, etc.

Comment: @IanSeol How about now?

Comment: {1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0} returns NaN for me

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for me with a little tweak!

Comment: @IanSeol Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
[20.0, 20.0] = 20.0
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0] = NO MODE
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0] = [3.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0] = [4.0, 5.0]
[-1.0, 2.0, -1.0, 2.0] = [-1.0, 2.0]
```

Code:

```
public class Mode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double test1[] = { 20.0, 20.0 };
        double test2[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 };
        double test3[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0 };
        double test4[] = { 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0 };

        System.out.println(getMode(test1));
        System.out.println(getMode(test2));
        System.out.println(getMode(test3));
        System.out.println(getMode(test4));
    }

    private static String getMode(double arr[]) {
        double checked[] = new double[arr.length];
        int occurrences[] = new int[arr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (!arrayContains(checked, arr[i])) {
                checked[i] = arr[i];
                occurrences[i] = arrayCount(arr, arr[i]);
            }
        }

        int lowest[] = sorted(occurrences, true);
        int highest[] = sorted(occurrences, false);

        if (arraysEqual(lowest, highest) && highest.length > 1) {
            return "NO MODE";
        }

        int j = 0;
        Double modes[] = new Double[arr.length];
        int most_occurrence = highest[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; ++i) {
            if (occurrences[i] == most_occurrence) {
                modes[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        double result[] = removeNullValues(modes);
        return result.length == 0 ? "Error" : result.length > 1 ? arrayToString(result) : Double.toString(result[0]);
    }

    private static boolean arrayContains(double arr[], double value) {
        return arrayCount(arr, value) > 0;
    }

    private static int arrayCount(double arr[], double value) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] == value) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static boolean arraysEqual(int a[], int b[]) {
        if (a.length != b.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static double[] removeNullValues(Double arr[]) {
        Double result[] = new Double[arr.length];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] != null) {
                result[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        // trim array
        double realResult[] = new double[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
            realResult[i] = result[i];
        }
        return realResult;
    }

    private static void sort(int arr[], boolean ascending) {
        int t = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; ++j) {
                if (ascending ? arr[j + 1] < arr[j] : arr[j + 1] > arr[j]) {
                    t = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] sorted(int arr[], boolean ascending) {
        int result[] = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            result[i] = arr[i];
        }

        sort(result, ascending);
        return result;
    }

    public static String arrayToString(double[] a) {
        int iMax = a.length - 1;
        if (iMax == -1) {
            return "[]";
        } else {
            String res = "[";

            int i = 0;
            while(true) {
                res += a[i];
                if (i == iMax) {
                    return res + "]";
                }

                res += ", ";
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is O(nlog(n)) on average.

The idea is first to sort the array, then just iterate it once to find the most repeated number.

```
public static Double getMostFrequentElement(double[] a) {
    quickSort(a, 0, a.length-1); // Instead of Arrays.sort(a); O(nlog(n))
    return getMostFrequentElementInSortedArray(a); // O(n)
}

private static double getMostFrequentElementInSortedArray(double[] sortedArr) {
    if(sortedArr.length == 0){
        return Double.NaN;
    }else if(sortedArr.length == 1){
        return sortedArr[0];
    }

    int maxCount = 1, currCount = 1;
    double result = Double.NaN, curr = sortedArr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
        if (curr == sortedArr[i]) {
            currCount++;

            if (currCount == maxCount) {
                result = Double.NaN;
            } else if (currCount > maxCount) {
                result = curr;
                maxCount = currCount;
            }
        } else {
            curr = sortedArr[i];
            currCount = 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Sorting
public static void quickSort(double[] arr, int begin, int end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, begin, end);

        quickSort(arr, begin, partitionIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, end);
    }
}

private static int partition(double[] arr, int begin, int end) {
    double pivot = arr[end];
    int i = (begin-1);

    for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            double swapTemp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = swapTemp;
        }
    }

    double swapTemp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = swapTemp;

    return i+1;
}
```

Output examples:

```
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{20.0, 20.0}); // 20.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0}); // NaN
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0}); // 1.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0}); // 1.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0}); // 2.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0}); // 1.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0}); // 2.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{2.0, 5.0}); // NaN
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{2.0}); // 2.0
getMostFrequentElement(new double[]{}); // NaN
```